# "FATAL: database does not exist" on postres, login is not working through app

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, roles

I have these three steps bellow which I am executing every moment that I need to create a new environment for my app, the step 3 is just part of code...

On the first step I create the database, second step I make the Roles and Users, and at the end I am making the structure, creating the tables of database.

In my APP I try to connect the database by hibernate, this way:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/LGP_VREF</property>
    <property name="connection.username">lgp_appuserdb</property>
    <property name="connection.password">ccccc</property>
...
```

Usually I don't work with postgres, so I guess I am not understanding the postgres's concept of Roles and Users.

I am getting the following error:

> DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1831 - An exception occurred while acquiring a
>   poolable resource. Will retry. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   FATAL: database "LGP_VREF" does not exist

**Why am not I getting the login? Everything seems ok.**

My steps for a new ambient:

step 1

```
CREATE DATABASE "LGP_VREF" WITH OWNER "postgres" ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'pt_BR.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'pt_BR.UTF-8';
```

step 2

```
CREATE USER adm_userdb_temp WITH PASSWORD 'aaaaa' SUPERUSER VALID UNTIL '2013-07-07';
CREATE USER adm_userdb WITH PASSWORD 'bbbbb' SUPERUSER;
CREATE USER lgp_appuserdb WITH PASSWORD 'ccccc';

CREATE ROLE appUsers INHERIT;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO appUsers;
GRANT appUsers TO lgp_appuserdb;
```

step 3

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    data_entrada timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    descricao character varying(255),
    experiencia character varying(255),
    formacao character varying(255),
    informacoes character varying(255)
);


ALTER TABLE public.students OWNER TO appUsers;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Database exits? Can you cross check this at db end? As the error clearly says that Database does not exits.

Comment: People, I am sure exists the database, I use the pgAdmin III so, I can see and access it easily, but through the app I get the situation explained above. Thanks.

Comment: All looks fine to me, which suggests that maybe your ORM isn't connecting to the same host/port that you're creating the DB on. Do you have multiple PostgreSQL instances? Otherwise, check `\l` in `psql`; confirm that the DB is present and is shown in upper case.